# Xamarin.iOS- ProjectDir:No such file or directory (appName.iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Getting compilation error in xamarin.iOS project-

> /Users/gsps/Desktop/MyFolder/projectName/iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/projectName.iOS.app:
>   Error: ${ProjectDir}: No such file or directory (projectName.iOS)

I have Cleaned, Rebuild & Restarted machine but this didn't solved my problem. When I am going to the given location finding the same file that looks like deleted or corrupted(See screenshot). I have recently updated Xamarin & xCode to latest version.

Error screenshot below:

[image]
File/Directory screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question. After searching a lot I found that In **iOS Bundle Signing**, I have declared `Additional Argument` as `${ProjectDir}`. When I removed It, I have compiled my project successfully.